# React Navigation 5 - My stack route's params are not merged

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

### Problem

In react navigation 5, when you push the same stack screen, params are merged right? At least, that was the behavior I was getting until I move this stack screen to a parent stack navigator. Now, the params are not merged when pushing the screen from a child, and then pushing the same screen (2 instance of the same). Any ideas why is this happening?

### Navigation Structure

### Before:

```
-RootStack (Stack Navigator)
    -TabNavigator (Bottom Tab Navigator)
         -HomeStacks (Stack Navigator)
             -Feed (Stack Screen)
             -CommentsStack (Stack Navigator)
                  -Comments (Stack Screen)
```

With this, when navigating from "Feed" to "Comments" like this:

```
  navigation.push("Comments", { contentId: "123" });
```

and then, in the comments screen, pushing the same with:

```
  navigation.push("Comments", { otherParam: "54" });
```

the second instance of the screen "Comments" had both params (merged) contentId and otherParam.

### After

```
-RootStack (Stack Navigator)
    -Comments (Stack Screen)
    -TabNavigator (Bottom Tab Navigator)
         -HomeStacks (Stack Navigator)
             -Feed (Stack Screen)
```

With this, when navigating from "Feed" to "Comments" like this:

```
  navigation.push("Comments", { contentId: "123" });
```

and then, in the comments screen, pushing the same with:

```
  navigation.push("Comments", { otherParam: "54" });
```

I only get "otherParam" in the second "Comments" screen instance (not merged).

Comment: Push adds a new screen. There's no way params were merged before if you used push like you wrote. If you want to navigate to existing screen and merge params, then use navigate.

Comment: @satya164 check this snack https://snack.expo.io/@victoriomolina/stackactions-reference-%7C-react-navigation  it is the same behaviour I had with the first navigation structure. I guess it will be because of the nested navigator.

Comment: You're navigating to a nested screen in the snack which is different from what you wrote here. Like I said you should use navigate instead of push if this want params to be merged

Comment: Sorry, that was a fast example. Okey, I will go with navigate for merging params!